# Не может прочитать из GzipStream

Tags: c#, .net, gzip

Не декомпресит данные. При чтении из GzipStream количество считанных байтов = 0. Версия .NET 3.5, в чем может быть дело?

```
zipStream = new GzipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
int count = zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Нужно перевести мемористрим в начало: `memoryStream.Position = 0`

Comment: Я сделал после записи в поток перемещение позиции, не помогло, пошаговая отладка также показывает 0 считанных байтов.

Comment: Э-э-э... Посмотрел код внимательней. Писать нужно в `zipStream`, а не в `memoryStream`.

Comment: Изначально так и было, но поток закрыт на запись, запись ведется в случае компрессии, а из мемори стрим забираются данные. А тут InvalidOperationException бросает если попытаться записать, и поток открыт только на чтение при декомпрессии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось прочитать

```
memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
var b = zipStream.ReadByte();
int count = zipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```